# How to extract a substring which includes brackets in brackets in python?

Tags: python

I have some difficulties to write a RE to extract some string as below

```
(a+b)*((c+d)/6)
```

what I want to extract are

```
a+b
(c+d)/6
```

when I use something like r `"\(([A-Za-z0-9_]+)\)"` it only extract `a+b` and `c+d`

but `(c+d)/6` is not found

Comment: `(\w\+\w)|(\(\w\+\w\)\/\d)` ? https://regex101.com/r/NJT23u/1

Comment: (.*?)(?:[.*?]|$)    > https://regex101.com/r/qmEmhJ/1